# How to pass a BASH script parameter to ConEmu?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, conemu, cmder

How can I pass a bash script command line parameter to ConEmu?
For example I would like to execute MyBashScript.sh on startup.

ConEmu64.exe /??? MyBashScript.sh

Comment: The answer depends on what do you expect at the end of script execution. And actually on which bash would you like to use. Remember, that ConEmu is not a shell at all.

Comment: I'd like to use simple linux shell commands (cat, sed, etc.).